# How to resolve a TransientObjectException that honestly does not make sense

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, tags, transient

I am using Hibernate 4.1 and I'm getting the following exception whenever I try and store a list of transient tags that have been added to a collection for an object.

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.myapplication.domain.Tag
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:811)
```

Now, I need to explain things a bit. My Tag class has a collection of synonyms. Before I added this relationship, I never got this exception and everything worked fine:

```
<class name="com.myapplication.domain.Tag">
    <id name="id" column="tag_id" type="long">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="term" index="termIndex" unique="true" not-null="true" />
    <property name="description" />
    <property name="approved" />

    <many-to-one name="masterTag" column="master_tag_id"
                 class="com.myapplication.domain.Tag" />

    <bag name="synonyms">
        <key column="master_tag_id" />
        <one-to-many class="com.myapplication.domain.Tag" />
    </bag>
</class>
```

Here is how an object maps tags. The `Tags` class is just a component class. Tags.list is the actual collection that Hibernate is persisting.

```
    <component name="tags">
        <bag name="list" table="user_to_tag">
            <key column="user_id" />
            <many-to-many class="com.myapplication.domain.Tag" column="tag_id"/>
        </bag>
    </component>
```

The tags I am trying to save in the database actually don't contain any synonyms at all, so I don't believe it has anything to do with transient synonym tags. I don't want these to cascade, which is why I have not given it a cascade attribute on the `<bag>` tag.

User's will typically insert tags into the system via a list of strings. I did it this way because I want to create tags or link to existing tags at the same time on the fly whenever the object containing tags is saved. Maybe this is more trouble than it's worth? If I only let them link to tags that exist, then I know I can solve my problem. Perhaps the complexity of dealing with on-the-fly tag creation in Hibernate is a bit more than it can deal with?

This is the method I am using to save new/existing tags all in one go. Whenever an object is saved to the database, it first calls into this method to persist the tags collection:

```
public void saveAll(Tags tags) {
    List<Tag> tagsToOverwrite = new ArrayList<Tag>();

    Iterator<Tag> i = tags.getList().iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        Tag tag = i.next();

        if(stopListService.hasWord(tag.getTerm())) {
            i.remove();
        } else {
            if(tag.isTransient()) {
                Tag dbTag = findByTerm(tag.getTerm());

                if(dbTag == null) {
                    save(tag);
                } else {
                    tagsToOverwrite.add(dbTag);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    tags.overwriteAll(tagsToOverwrite);
}
```

For some reason, it fails on `Tag dbTag = findByTerm(tag.getTerm());` That's when it throws the `TransientObjectException`. This method is just a simple query:

```
public Tag findByTerm(final String term) {
    Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(
        "from Tag tag " +
        "where tag.term = :term "
    );

    return (Tag) query
        .setParameter("term", term.toLowerCase())
        .setCacheable(true)
        .uniqueResult(); // This is where the exception gets thrown specifically
}
```

I am not sure why this method would throw this exception, because all I want to do is simply check to see if it's in the database or not before I save it. Why is complaining about objects not being saved when all I am doing is querying it?

If the tags list only contains a single tag, the method works. It only fails when the number of transient tags to save is 2 or more. For example, this fails:

```
@Test
public void saveShouldPersistTransientTags() {
    User user = userRepository.find(1);
            // makes list of 3 tags that are transient (id = 0)
    user.getTags().setTagsAsString("training learning business");

    userRepository.save(user);
    flush();

    user = userRepository.find(1);
    assertEquals(3, user.getTags().getList().size());
}
```

Here is the UserRepository.save() method:

```
@Override
public void save(User user) {
    tagRepository.saveAll(user.getTags());

    super.save(user);
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to save all of the transient tags first (or look them up in the database) before the user is saved. Yet, Hibernate seems to want to persists the `user.tags.list` collection during the call `tagRepository.saveAll(user.getTags());` in the location where the exception is being thrown anyway, even though I never asked it to.

Of course, if I remove the `synonyms` collection from the Hibernate mapping, this test passes without any problems. It only fails when I enable the `synonym` collection, and it only fails when it gets to the `learning` tag (the `training` tag is not found in the database, and is persisted just fine.)

Any idea as to why the synonym collection is causing this problem?

If I can't figure this out soon, in the interest of saving time, I am highly tempted to just use JDBC for this, as Hibernate's complexity in cases like this can't be such a good thing. I think this may even be a bug given the behaviour. It still doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are ready to query Hibernate may look at its managed objects.  Those that are dirty it will attempt to flush to the database so the query is hitting an up-to-date datastore.  Somewhere in your code you are adding unmanaged (probably new?) synonyms to the collection, then when Hibernate tries to 'help' you by flushing the dirty object you get that exception.

Comment: The code that runs this test does not deal with synonyms though :( If I simply remove the synonym collection from the Tag mapping, the test passes. I have no idea how synonyms could be getting added. In the debugger, the synonym list for all 3 transient tags is empty. I will keep looking. This one has me totally stumped.

Comment: You could comment out every other test and run only this test and see how it behaves.  You could also turn on hibernate logging and will likely get a bunch of information.

Comment: Yeah, the test fails in 100% isolation. I guess I'll turn on all of the logs to see what's up. I hope I can find it. I am somewhat convinced this is a bug in hibernate. I am tempted to just use Spring's JdbcTemplate for tags.

Comment: According to the debug logs, it seems that Hibernate is trying to save the entire tags collection during the saveAll() method :( Since there are 2 more transient objects in the collection that I have yet to process, it's complaining. I don't want it to do this. How can I make it not do that?

Comment: back to my answer, if your instance of Tags is a managed object, then it's going to try to flush all of the Tag collection within Tags because it sees that your instance of Tags is dirty.  One solution is to separate things so you aren't adding a Tag to Tags until the Tag is already persistent.  This is assuming Tags is also a persistent object.  Perhaps you could also not cascade the Tag collection in Tags.

Comment: Tags is a component object. It doesn't represent anything that is stored in the database - it just wraps the `List<Tag> list` in the object that has a collection of tags. All of the tag logic is in this class, so I can reuse it across many objects that need tags. What I don't understand is why does it want to flush the `List<Tag>` when there's a synonym collection, but it doesn't want to flush it when I remove it.

Comment: I am also not cascading any of my tag relationships, as you can see from hibernate mappings. There's no cascading at all.

Comment: I guess the solution is to simply add the tags that require saving into a temporary collection, and then save them after all of the querying is done. This works - query all of the tag terms first, and then save all of the new ones later at the same time. I still don't understand why Hibernate never complained about this before I introduced the synonym mapping, as the synonyms have nothing to do with this problem at all. I think it should have complained about this long before I added it, which is probably a bug in Hibernate.

Comment: Does your synonyms collection in Tag do lazy initialization?  I.e. if it's null then return a new empty collection?  If so then your Tag will appear dirty to hibernate and it's not a hibernate bug it's an application bug.